# python match case part of a string

Tags: python, match, python-3.10

I want to know if I can use match cases within Python to match within a string - that is, if a string contains the match case.  Example:

```
mystring = "xmas holidays"
match mystring:
      case "holidays":
           return true
      case "workday":
           return false
```

I can see why it wouldn't, since this could potentially match several cases at once, but I wanted to know if it was possible.

Comment: Can you share the error message ? Please not that this is only available in `python 3.10`.

Comment: An approach along the lines of [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70680363/2476977) could work, though any of those is probably overkill for this kind of issue.

Answer (score 12):

You could use the `[*_]` wildcard sequence capture pattern: https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#sequence-patterns

```py
def is_holiday(yourstring: str):
    match yourstring.split():
        case [*_, "holidays"]:
            return True
        case [*_, "workday"]:
            return False


print(is_holiday("xmas holidays"))
```

Comment: This is the answer IFF the user is looking for a complete substring that is separated by spaces.  If however they wanted to look for "holiday" instead of holidays, this answer would not work.  That said, this is an AWESOME answer showing the power of sequence wildcard capture which is definitely underutilized

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use the [guard](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#adding-conditions-to-patterns) feature along with capture:

```
>>>my_str = "iwill/predict_something"
>>>match my_str:
...    case str(x) if 'predict' in x:
...        print("match!")
...    case _:
...        print("nah, dog")
...
match!
```

Answer (score 6):

In `match` statement, [strings are compared using `==` operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/) which means that `case` patterns must be exactly equal to the `match` expression(`mystring` in this case) .

In order to solve this problem you can create a custom class which inherit from `str` and overrides the `__eq__` method. This method should delegate to `__contains__`.

```
>>> class MyStr(str):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...             return self.__contains__(other)
... 
>>> 
>>> mystring = MyStr("xmas holidays")
>>> match mystring:
...     case "holiday":
...             print("I am here...")
... 
I am here...
```

Comment: Raymond Hettinger (long time Python core developer) recently did [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72596437/12671057) and didn't say anything negative about it, so I'm guessing it's not a bad thing...

Comment: @KellyBundy oh thank you for your comment. Huge fan of Raymond Hettinger here. I didn't find overriding `__eq__` to delegate to `__contains__` as a good pattern in the first place. I will edit my answer to remove those statements.

Comment: I can't test with `match` right now, but I think these [two variations](https://tio.run/##fY0xDsIwEAT7e8V1tiVEQ4OQ/AQqHnBKHEexFJ3N@SjyeifI0CG23FnNlk2XzJdrkdbCOtSK9@2hYquKuwEemeKMRPFJZGtc5xNmXeIXfiJRX8KdYGJ8DwGKJFbbfWYYw2Qceo9mDMYBwO@7foUej@pMFDLrkLgS/fe1tgM) would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Having just finished reading [PEP-636](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/), I see two distinct possibilities for using pattern matching here.

First, use a match-all pattern and add a condition

```py
mystring = "xmas holidays"
match mystring:
    case x if "holidays" in x:
        return True
    case x if "workday" in x:
        return False
```

Second, subclass `str` and override its `__equals__` to perform a `__contains__` check. There are many ways to write this, so here is a few

```py
mystring = "xmas holidays"
match Substring(mystring):
    case "holidays":
        return True
    case "workday":
        return False


class Substring(str):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__contains__(other)

class Substring(str):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other in self

class Substring(str):
    __eq__ = str.__contains__
```

Over all, I think that this is not a good opportunity to use Python's pattern matching. The conceptual issue I have with the `Substring` class is that the [`__eq__` implementations end up not being symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).